# Google Drive API write a new drive file thats a not a Drive 'viewer' type

Tags: python, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm getting going with GooG Drive API. I've successfully stepped through the quickstart.py tutorial/example.  All good.

The file that appears in my Drive opens as a Drive 'viewer' file, rather than an editable file, which is what i need.  i'm guessing its the MIMEtype, but the document IS a .txt file, so i'm not sure what else it should be set to.  so how do i write it as a Drive editable file type ???

thanks

Dav-o

```
media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
body = {
  'title': 'My document',
  'description': 'A test document',
  'mimeType': 'text/plain'
}

file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
pprint.pprint(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are uploading the file as a txt, which is a format not editable with any of the Google editors.

You should convert the file into the corresponding native Google format to make it editable in the Drive default viewer:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

To enable conversion during upload, you have to set `convert=True` in the insert request:

```
file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body, convert=True).execute()
```